# Как в git задать разным локальным репозиториям разные user.name и user.email?

Tags: git, config, repository

Как в git задать разным локальным репозиториям разные user.name и user.email?

Например, есть папки

```
C/First/
C/Second/
```

Я хочу, чтобы кода я в Git bash перехожу в папку First и делают коммиты, то коммиты и все манипуляции делались от одного пользователя.
А когда в Git bash перехожу в папку Second и делаю в ней манипуляции, то чтобы они сохранялись под другим "пользователем".

Answer (score 4):

Верно предполагаете, это в локальном конфиге. Задать в нем имя и почту можно вот так:

```
$ git config --local user.name "John Doe"
$ git config --local user.email johndoe@example.com
```